# Segmentation fault for reading 31,622,400 characters from a file

Tags: c++

Here is the source code:

```
int main() {
    int secondsInYear = 366*24*60*60; // Equals 31,622,400
    short int data[secondsInYear];
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen ("stat", "r");
    fread(data, sizeof(short int), secondsInYear, pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
}
```

on line `fopen("stat", "r")` it gives me the segmentation fault error! If I read `secondsInYear/10` characters it will execute without any problem, So what seems to be the problem? And what's the solution?

Comment: This is definitely C, because C++ doesn't have VLA's.

Comment: @ybungalobill : GCC allows it in C++ as an extension, and changing the tag invalidates all the existing answers.

Comment: @ildjarn well, feel free to change it back than. Still it's C.

Comment: @ybungalobill secondsInYear would be optimized to a const or even just a literal value so the array isn't variable length

Comment: @Will03uk : `secondsInYear` must actually be declared `const` in order for that to be true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're creating a massive array on the stack. So you are hitting a stackoverflow. :)

You should dynamically allocate that array instead.

```
short int *data = new short int[secondsInYear];
```

and be sure to delete it later:

```
delete[] data;
```

Comment: Better still, use `Boost.ScopedArray` which will clean up after any exception.  No manual `delete` needed.

Comment: `delete[]`  Also, use a vector instead.

Answer (score 6):

That's way too big to fit the stack (the `data` array). Use `new` instead.

```
short *data = new short[secondsInYear];
```

After you are done with the array, you should `delete [] data` if the program continues running.

Not sure if it fits your case but I hear C++ programmers use `std::vector` instead of plain arrays for most things.

```
std::vector<short> shorts;
```